# MongoDB aborting when running mongod command on terminal

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

when i run `mongod` command on ubuntu terminal i get this error:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.341+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.348+05:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.349+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.349+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":9479,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"E7250"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.349+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2004","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.349+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"20.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.349+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.350+05:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.350+05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":919}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-28T22:27:29.350+05:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

mongod process is running when i enter command `sudo systemctl status mongod`

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena>
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-10-28 22:02:55 PKT; 32min ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 7566 (mongod)
     Memory: 159.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─7566 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

Oct 28 22:02:55 E7250 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
```

what went wrong?

**etc/mongod.conf file**

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: From the error it seems you would need to execute as root, so `sudo mongo <something else>`

Comment: Can you please provide your config file?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit this one >> /etc/mongod.conf??

Comment: @GytisTG running with sudo mongod , it gives >> {"t":{"$date":"2020-10-29T00:45:01.765+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-29T00:45:01.765+05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":48}}

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i included the mongod.conf info in question please have a look.

Comment: I think you mixed the `mongod` **service** which you typically start with `sudo systemctl start mongod` and the `mongo` shell. See [Start the mongo Shell and Connect to MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/index.html#start-the-mongo-shell-and-connect-to-mongodb) and [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/index.html)

Comment: Your config file says `dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb` but the log says `"dbPath":"/data/db"` somewhere you mixed up something.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

1. Stop mongod process by entering the following command in terminal: `sudo systemctl stop mongod`
2. You have to make directory for "dbPath" with following command: `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` and `` sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db ``
3. Then run `sudo mongod --port 27017`

Done!

you can't run `sudo systemctl start mongod` and `sudo mongod --port 27017` at same time. Stop mongod by `sudo systemctl stop mongod` then run `sudo mongod --port 27017`

Hope this solution works for all who have same problem.

Comment: Or vice versa. `sudo systemctl start mongod` should also work.

Comment: Port 27017 is the default port, so `sudo mongod` should also work.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the mongod service with `sudo systemctl start mongod` then the systemd reads the service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`.

By default it sets the user to `mongod` and reads the config file `/etc/mongod.conf`:

```
[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
```

When you start the service with `sudo mongod` then your mongo runs as `root` and no config file is read.

In the default `mongod.conf` file the dbPath is set to

```
# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
```

However, when `dbPath` is not provided then default `/data/db` applies.

You may start the MongoDB with `sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf` which correspond to `sudo systemctl start mongod` - however your mongod is running as `root` rather than `mongod` user.

Note, usually you don't edit settings directly in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` file. Create a copy to `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` and customize this copy. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206315/whats-the-difference-between-usr-lib-systemd-system-and-etc-systemd-system